# How to build a model with multiple sine waves

Tags: python, graph, trigonometry

So I have a data set that I need to find a model function for, with sine or cosine waves. I have been trying to find a guide on how to model this with sine waves in python, but it seems that all the examples I could I find were only using one sine wave and I need multiple waves to map this. If anybody knows how to map with multiple sine waves that would be great.

```
y-axis = [-0.67818604651162795, -0.6547391304347826, -0.64717777777777785, -0.7291399999999999, -0.76626470588235296, -0.73485714285714299, -0.74283333333333346, -0.7376538461538461, -0.7194799999999999, -0.75478571428571439, -0.75462857142857143, -0.6249473684210527, -0.62299999999999989, -0.66933333333333334, -0.71358823529411775, -0.73843589743589755, -0.76109803921568631, -0.81569230769230749, -0.74926470588235294, -0.70762857142857138, -0.7171923076923078, -0.68428, -0.71395454545454551, -0.74174999999999991, -0.7476666666666667, -0.69532727272727279, -0.64591836734693875, -0.68385294117647066, -0.60952941176470576, -0.63846666666666674, -0.72566666666666679]
x-axis = [6040, 6080, 6120, 6160, 6200, 6240, 6280, 6320, 6360, 6400, 6440, 6480, 6520, 6560, 6600, 6640, 6680, 6720, 6760, 6800, 6840, 6880, 6920, 6960, 7000, 7040, 7080, 7120, 7160, 7200, 7240]
```

Stackoverflow won't let me post pictures yet so here is the data if you want to look at it.

Comment: Python's math module has a sine function which can be used multiple times in an expression, so I'm not sure what your actual question is. Do you want to learn how to use Fourier analysis? There are plenty of books and tutorials out their and I'm sure that there are implementations of the corresponding algorithms in SciPy

Comment: Will it give me a best fit for the data I have?

Comment: "best fit" doesn't have a 100% clear meaning here. I'm no expert but I would imagine that there is a trade-off between accuracy (going through or almost through all your data points) and smoothness. SciPy is a vast library and it does include things like Fast Fourier Transforms and other tools for signal processing. I would first decide on what I want to actually do mathematically with the data and only then try to figure out how to implement it in Python.

Comment: I want to be able to adjust the accuracy vs smoothness. That way I can find a decent fit that has an appropriate amount of variables to work with as needed. The only way I can do that is to just try different variations. So I suppose the problem is that I do not know how to set up, efficiently, any sort of combination of sine waves to even get started. I don't think the math module has what I need, but after looking around I think numpy.fft would work for my needs